# Jquery ajax load page em loop infinito

Tags: jquery

Possuo um botão em uma pagina que ao clicar o mesmo realiza o seguinte codigo:

Obs: Sempre q clico nesse botão o mesmo recarrega uma pagina php com dados em html, os scripts do jquery.
Porém chega um ponto q ele fica em loop na busca dos scripts do jquery.

Alguma idéia do porque isso ocorre?

```
$('#return').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clearChildren(document.getElementById('savepesquisa'));
    $('form')[0].reset();
    blockUnblok(0,idvarejo,4);
    $.ajax({
        url: "pesquisas.php",
        type: "GET",
        success:function(data){$('#loadhtml').html(data);}
    });
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function blockUnblok(option,idvarejo,status,iduser){
    if(option == 1){
        var blockId = $.ajax({
                            url: 'dadosPS.php?ps=BlockId&id=' + idvarejo + '&idStatus=' + status,
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false
                        }).responseText;
    }else if(option == 0){
        var unblockId = $.ajax({
                            url: 'dadosPS.php?ps=ReleaseId&id=' + idvarejo + '&idStatus=' + status,
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false
                        }).responseText;
    }else if(option == 2){
        var updateAgenda = $.ajax({
                            url: 'dadosPS.php?ps=UpdateAgendamento&idStatus=' + status + '&varejo=' + idvarejo + '&idUser=' + iduser,
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false
                        }).responseText;
    }else{}
}
```

Comment: Esta função 'blockUnblok' é sua?

Comment: sim Wictor ela executa uma consulta ajax assincrona.

Comment: Poste o código dela também, o problema pode esta lá.

Comment: Atualizei com o código.

Comment: Esse codigo do blockUnblock realiza um simples update onde nao pego retorno de nada.

Comment: Esse `blockUnblock` está completo? Porque não consigo ver ele atualizando nada, apenas pegando o `responseText` de uma solicitação **síncrona**.

Comment: O que vem de resultado da requisição feita em `pesquisas.php`? Existe algum **script** vindo junto nesse resultado?

Comment: Só com os trechos postados não faz sentido essa repetição que você menciona.

Comment: No pesquisas.php retorna uma pagina completa com inputs e funcoes . e é carregada em uma div. quando clico no botão return , ele uma função limpa os inputs marcados e carrega novamente por ajax a pagina pesquisas.php.